# Navigate Fragment1 to Fragment2

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

Im trying to open a new fragment from other fragment int the method onClick of my RecyclerView.ViewHolder, I retrieve my datas from firebase.

But it throw the next error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.NewsClickedListener.onClick(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
>                         at es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Models.NewsViewHolder$1.onClick(NewsViewHolder.java:27)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Ive created a interface:

```
package es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo;

import android.view.View;

public interface NewsClickedListener {
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

This interface is implements in a new AppCompatActivity:

```
package es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Fragments.DetalleFragment;


    public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NewsClickedListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            DetalleFragment df = new DetalleFragment();
            df.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_detalle,df);
            ft.setTransition(ft.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

And I instance it in this class, implements its methods:

```
package es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Models;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.NewsClickedListener;
import es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.R;

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;

    NewsClickedListener newsClickedListener;
    public NewsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    newsClickedListener.onClick(view);
            }
        });
    }

    //Datos que obtenemos de firebase y los usamos en la cardview, se llaman desde cada categoria
    public void setTitular(String titular){
        TextView post_titular = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        post_titular.setText(titular);
    }
    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
    //Datos para el detalle, lo llama el fragmento de detalle y dependera de cada opcion elegida
    public void setTitularDetalle(String titular){
        TextView post_titular_detalle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtCabeceraDetalle);
        post_titular_detalle.setText(titular);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add your Recyclerview adapter code to the post

Comment: You never assigned `newsClickedListener` to anything in your code here

Comment: Again, please show the adapter code. Or you need to assign `holder.newsClickedListener` to whatever class implemented that interface

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a callback method to tell to your host `Activity` from `Fragment1` to change the fragment.

Create a listener such as:

```
public interface NewsClickedListener
{
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

which will be implemented by the `Activity` which hosts the two fragments:

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NewsClickedListener
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        DetalleFragment df = new DetalleFragment();
        df.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fm.replace(R.id.fragment_detalle,df);
        fm.setTransition(fm.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fm.addToBackStack(null);
        fm.commit();
    }
}
```

Then you have to put a `NewsClickedListener` instance in your `Fragment1` and change your `itemView.setOnClickListener` like this:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        newsClickedListenerInstance.onClick(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello! Ive just tried this solution but It throw the same error. Thanks

Comment: You need to show how to assign `newsClickedListenerInstance`

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont know where I should make it... Its my first app in android...